# How to convert fraction into floating point number in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, fractions

Hello I have a really simple qestion, in my app I have an EditText and what I would like for instance is this:

If I write 1/2 I would like 0.5 in the field.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why I get downvotes ? Are you serious ?

Comment: Please hover over the down-vote arrow to see why, and yes, we're serious.

Comment: You are getting downvotes because of your lack of research. This is not a tutorial site, nor a Google replacement.

Answer (score 0):

only add any dight/any other digit or any text with this fraction?
need info 
Why you "dont want to split the string and then covert to individual strings to numbers and then divide them to have result"?

I am not aware of any built-in function to do that so the simplest solution:

```
double parse(String ratio) {
    if (ratio.contains("/")) {
        String[] rat = ratio.split("/");
        return Double.parseDouble(rat[0]) / Double.parseDouble(rat[1]);
    } else {
        return Double.parseDouble(ratio);
    }
}
```

It also covers the case where you have integer representation of ratio

```
parse("1/2") => 0.5
parse("3/7") => 0.42857142857142855
parse("1") => 1.0
```